# Number formatting: big.mark with "." and decilmal.mark with "," it gives NAs

Tags: r, format

I have the following table:

```
structure(list(grup_CNAE_Red = c("Aliments i begudes no alcohòliques", 
"Begudes alcohòliques i tabac", "Vestit i calçat"), despesatotal = c(90668.3942513707, 
9350.70966336, 21808.88895535), proporcio_total = c(16.4337534376051, 
1.69482715937661, 3.9528868554426)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tabyl", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), core = structure(list(grup_CNAE_Red = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Aliments i begudes no alcohòliques", 
"Begudes alcohòliques i tabac", "Vestit i calçat", "Habitatge", 
"Mobles i parament de la llar", "Salut", "Transport", "Comunicacions", 
"Oci i cultura", "Educació", "Restaurants i hotels", "Altres béns i serveis"
), class = "factor"), despesatotal = c(90668.3942513707, 9350.70966336, 
21808.88895535, 186645.44797435, 24265.96063364, 22709.57989815, 
60941.60103453, 17670.69007283, 24405.55628082, 8274.5920409, 
43167.89349882, 41811.23204347), despesamonetaria = c(89883.1722917393, 
9339.26085002, 21794.62559391, 63341.3240054499, 24245.31065782, 
22706.3181967, 60847.98764934, 17638.41977893, 24402.01538905, 
8137.57745883, 41326.4730733121, 41519.99268768)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame"), tabyl_type = "two_way", totals = "row")
```

And I want to convert `despesatotal` such that thousands are stated in "." and decimals in ",", and rounded to 2 digits.

Also, `proporcio_total`, decimals should be with "," and rounded to 2 digits.

When I try to do it with `format` I only get either NA values or character (but I need numeric values).

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr::mutate()` you could try this, however, the values will be characters not numeric. I'm not sure you can format R numeric values with thousands separators and retain the numeric type.

You could round to two decimal places with `round` and retain the type as numeric. The decimal separator is, I think, linked to the operating system for your locale. You might try with `options(OutDec=",")` at the beginning of your script to control the decimal separator.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 |>
  mutate(despesatotal = format(despesatotal, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","),
         proporcio_total = format(round(proporcio_total, 2), decimal.mark = ","))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   grup_CNAE_Red                      despesatotal proporcio_total
#>   <chr>                              <chr>        <chr>          
#> 1 Aliments i begudes no alcohòliques "90.668,39"  "16,43"        
#> 2 Begudes alcohòliques i tabac       " 9.350,71"  " 1,69"        
#> 3 Vestit i calçat                    "21.808,89"  " 3,95"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But `despesatotal` and  `proporcio_total` should be numeric not character.

Comment: This is mentioned in the answer, I may be wrong,  but I do not think you can format numbers and retain them as type `numeric` in R. I include a suggestion for formatting the decimal point separator as your question; have you tried this? Usually formatted data is for presentation in tables where it should not matter that the formatting results in type character.

Comment: Oh thanks, sorry. Is there something for big mark? `options(OutDec=".")`but for thousands.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.